# inheritance error while using polymorphic object creation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FootWearItem class and a CartItem class, both of which inherit from ProductItem class. I also have a ShoppingCart class which holds a list containing CartItems.

I am testing the classes out in Main(); I am trying to add FootWearItems to ShoppingCart although I seem to be getting an error stating cannot convert ProductItem to CartItem.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
public abstract class ProductItem
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public ProductItem(string productCode, string description, double price)
        {
            ProductCode = productCode;
            Description = description;
            Price = price;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Product Code: " + ProductCode + "\nDescription: " + Description + "\nPrice: " + Price;
        }
    }


    public enum Gender
    {
        Men, Women
    }

    public class FootWearItem : ProductItem
    {
        public double Size { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        public FootWearItem(string productCode, string description, double price, double size, Gender gender) 
            : base (productCode, description, price)
        {
            Size = size;
            Gender = gender;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + "\nSize: " + Size + "\nGender" + Gender;
        }
    }

    public class CartItem : ProductItem
    {
        public int NumberItems { get; set; }
        public CartItem(string productCode, string description, double price, int numberItems) 
            : base(productCode, description, price)
        {
            NumberItems = numberItems;
        }
    }

    public class ShoppingCart
    {
        List<CartItem> cart;
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        private double total;


        public ShoppingCart()
        {
            cart = new List<CartItem>();
        }

        public void AddItem(CartItem item)
        {
            if(!cart.Contains(item))
            {
                cart.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Item is already in cart");
            }
        }
        public double TotalPrice()
        {
            foreach(CartItem i in cart)
            {
                total += i.Price;
            }

            return total;
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ProductItem i1 = new FootWearItem("A122", "black nike shoe", 50.99, 10.5, Gender.Men);
            ProductItem i2 = new FootWearItem("A122", "black nike shoe", 70.99, 9.5, Gender.Men);
            ProductItem i3 = new FootWearItem("A122", "black nike shoe", 60.99, 6, Gender.Women);

            ShoppingCart cart1 = new ShoppingCart();
            cart1.AddItem(i1);
            cart1.AddItem(i2);
            cart1.AddItem(i3);
        }
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: Your inheritance-chain is somehow strange. A `CartItem` is no `FootWearItem` and vice versa. What do you expect when you cast your newly created `FootWearItems` (e.g. `i1`) to `CarItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CartItem should contain ProductItem as a property — as it stands, ProductItem is not derived from CartItem and so cant be cast.

```
public class CartItem
{
    public int NumberItems { get; set; }
    public ProductItem Product { get; set; }

    public CartItem(ProductItem product, int numberItems)
    {
        Product = product;
        NumberItems = numberItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: @darego101 In particular your `CartItem` must not **derive** from `ProductItem`. Instead it should just **reference** it, e.g. by introducing a property in your `CartItem`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include modified CartItem class.

Comment: I think you'll want to create a CartItem to add to the cart:  cart1.AddItem(new CartItem(item1, numberItems: 12)) etc